# MSDTC (Distributed Transactions) support in MySQL

Tags: sql, mysql, msdtc

Does MySQL support MSDTC?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

not natively. it does support XA transactions (two-phase commit) so you could implement it yourself in an additional database abstraction layer.

Comment: I suppose I could, but I don't want to. Someone out there must have done this already.

Can someone point me to what's out there?

Comment: i've looked, and i don't see evidence of anyone else doing this and posting their work on the internet.